# RNN & Batches in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

The batche approach for RNN in Tensorflow is not clear to me. For example tf.nn.rnn Take as input list of Tensors [BATCH_SIZE x INPUT_SIZE]. We normally are feeding to session batches of data, so why it take list of batches not single batch?

This leads to next confusion for me:

```
data = []
for _ in range(0, len(train_input)):
    data.append(tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [CONST_BATCH_SIZE, CONST_INPUT_SIZE]))

lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(CONST_NUM_OF_HIDDEN_STATES)

val, state = tf.nn.rnn(lstm, data, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I pass list of Tensors [CONST_BATCH_SIZE x CONST_INPUT_OTPUT_SIZE] to `tf.nn.rnn` and got output value that is list of Tensors [CONST_BATCH_SIZE x CONST_NUM_OF_HIDDEN_STATES]. Now I want to use softmax for all HIDDEN_STATES outputs and need to calculate weights with matmaul + bias

Should I use for matmul:

```
weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([CONST_NUM_OF_HIDDEN_STATES, CONST_OTPUT_SIZE]))

for i in val:
  mult = tf.matmul(i, weight)

bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([CONST_OTPUT_SIZE]))
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(mult + bias)
```

Or should I create 2D array from `val` and then use `tf.matmul` without `for`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. output is batched data from RNN. For all the batch input probs will have the probability.

```
logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Comment: output of RNN  is 3D (list of 2d) and softmax_w is 2D that is the question: should I iterate in batches or create 2D array from 3D for outputs

Comment: can you write down those dimension with example, it would be easy to understand